# Possible reasons for Google Sign In returning SIGN_IN_FAILED 12500

Tags: google-signin, google-workspace

I have an app available for download which uses Google Sign In. Most people do not have any problem signing in using Google Sign in so I know it is set up correctly with the right keys. However very occasionally we see the following error.

```
SIGN_IN_FAILED 12500
```

The docs say

```
The sign in attempt didn't succeed with the current account.

Unlike SIGN_IN_REQUIRED. when seeing this error code, there is nothing user can do to recover from the sign in failure. Switching to another account may or may not help. Check adb log to see details if any.
```

I suspect something has been disabled by a GSuite admin but I cannot see anything you can do to disable Google Sign In. In GSuite help I read under “View and revoke third-party applications connected to the user's Google Account”:

```
You can revoke service access only after it's been granted. You can't preemptively block users from granting access to specific apps.
```

Can anyone suggest what could cause this - for example how I could reproduce this issue by setting something in my own GSuite account?

Comment: I'm completely unable to log in using one of my apps. Always throws 12500 error with no further explanation. No idea how to fix this, I've tried re-configuring everything etc. Seems like some undocumented change by Google or an issue with new apps (I have 6 existing apps that work, the latest one doesn't work).

Comment: I saw something about a SHA1 signature that can eiasily get copied wrong which might be something like that if it’s happening always.